# Using NaN value in MSChart gives Overflow Exception

Tags: mschart, nan, overflowexception

I'm working in a real time ploting appication with MSChart...I need to set some y values to `NaN` but I'm getting an overflow exception. Here is the part of the code where it happen:

```
if (j_ecg < 2569)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
        { 
         ECG.Points.AddXY(puntos_ecg[j_ecg].X,puntos_ecg[j_ecg].Y); 
        });
        j_ecg++;
    }
}

else
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ECG.Points[ecg_s].SetValueY(puntos_ecg[j_ecg].Y);
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++){ ECG.Points[ecg_s + j].SetValueY(double.NaN); }
        });


        j_ecg++;
        ecg_s++;
        if (ecg_s == 2560) { ecg_s = 0; }
    }
}
```

The Invokes are there to avoid cross threads issues.

Any idea of how can I do it for not getting the exception? I've try using unchecked keyword just before the `SetValueY` call but nothing changes.

Comment: They should probably give you something more informative than an overflow exception, but it doesn't make any sense for you to try to graph something that's not a number. After all, where would you put `NaN` on the axis?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is disabling autoscaling so that min/max don't need to be calculated:

```
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.Minimum = <your min>;
chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.Maximum = <your max>;
```

However you still need to have **at least one** real value in **one** of your series.
I recommend you keep track of your displayed values. If everything is NaN, stop plotting! When the next valid value comes in resume plotting.

Note: using zeroes instead of NaN is another solution.